# On enter key press change cursor position javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have form with two text fields and `onLoad="document.forms.obrazac.sifra.focus()"` I put cursor on the first field. Now I want when user press enter key to focus cursor on second field and then when enter is pressed again I want to submit my form.
How can I do that, thanks.

Comment: Just my 2 cents, but breaking browser default behavior is bad practice.

Comment: The tab key by default will go through your forms input elements, and the enter key by default will submit the form. It's best to leave it that way if it isn't a specific constraint of a project.

Comment: If Wolf87 has a request to do so, it's good to break the default behavior. It depends on what we're talking about: a web page or a web app.

Comment: It also depends on the audience. If the client explicitly required it because x or y reason, then go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely not good to break the default behavior. Btw, do you know the `autofocus` attribute in HTML?

If you absolutely need this, here you go:

```
document.forms.obrazac.onkeypress = function( e ) {
    // If the hit key is "Enter"
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {

        // Cross-browser handling for our dear friend @MaxArt :p
        var evt = e || window.event,
            target = evt.target || evt.srcElement,

        // Find the next input
            nextInput = target.nextSibling;
        while ( nextInput.tagName !== 'INPUT' && nextInput.nextSibling ) {
            nextInput = nextInput.nextSibling;
        }

        // And focus it
        nextInput.focus();

        // Finally, disable submitting IF there is no input after
        if ( nextInput !== this.elements[ this.elements.length - 1 ] ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: 1. Traditional event listening is deprecated everywhere. 2. `nextElementSibling` isn't supported by IE8-. 3. So `e.target` isn't.

Comment: 1. Wut? Where have you seen this? 2/3: Sure.

Comment: 1. Just everywhere. It's always recommended to separate HTML and Javascript, and to use more modern methods than the traditional registration model because you can attach multiple listeners for the same kind of event.

Comment: Do you see any HTML there? Of course, `addEventListener` is more modern. It isn't cross-browser however. The code in this answer is.

Comment: What if Wolf87 already had a traditionally registered event on that element? If you're going to pollute his DOM, at least warn him. Maybe he's using jQuery or other frameworks that help him registering event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Just a short not realy testet sample... just to give u an idea:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onKeyPress(args)
    {
        if(args.keyCode === 13)
            document.getElementById("tb2").focus();
    }       
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" onkeypress="onKeyPress(event);" id="tb1" />
    <input type="text" id="tb2" />
</body>
```

You could do the same on tb2 to submit the form there on "ENTER"
I would also use something like jQuery to bind the events in javascript, not directly in the markup.

Hope it helps.

@as i have started creating my sample there where no answers =)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't break the default behavior, it's pretty annoying and counterintuitive for the users, but if you really want to do it, you could do something like this with jquery:

```
$('#form').keydown(function(e) {
    if( e.keyCode === 13) {  // When "Shift + Enter"
        e.preventDefault();
        // focus on next field here.
    }
});
```

Instead of doing this, you would be better off just making the right tab order like this (with tabindex):

```
<input type="text" name="field1" tabindex=1 /><br />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
document.forms.obrazac.sifra.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) { // 13 === enter key
        e.preventDefault();
        this.nextSibling.focus();
    }
});
```

Mind these things:

1. I used `addEventListener`, but in IE8 and older you have to use `attachEvent("onkeyup"...` and checking the global `event` object. Moreover, `e.preventDefault();` becomes `e.returnValue = false;`
2. I supposed that `this.nextSibling` is the next field. Correct this to fit you DOM.

Comment: 1. `keyup` is the worst event to attach something on. 2. even when the next field is right after, `nextSibling` will most probably get a textNode. 3. `this` is `document.forms.obarazac.sifra`, not the element that triggered the event.

Comment: 1. Please explain. 2. "Probably" isn't the same thing as "certainly". I said what I supposed. 3. `document.forms.obarazac.sifra`, if it's presumably an input field, it's exactly what triggered the event.

Comment: 1. http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript 2. "most probably" is "most of the time" :). 3. The first time, yes. Not the second time.

Comment: 1. Not the point. We don't want to detect the input value, just the value of the pressed key. `keyup` is fine here. 2. I already said that it should be corrected to fit the DOM. 3. The second time it's ok to let the browser do the work, as Wolf87 said.